# increase timeout for springFramework transactionTemplate execute

Tags: java, spring, timeout, websphere, spring-transactions

I have a web application which is run in WebSphere, thus there is a timeout value of 120 seconds configure in `Total transaction lifetime timeout` at `Servers --> WebSphere application servers --> myServerName --> Container Services --> Transaction Service.`

So, if there is a transaction taking more than 120 seconds to response, it will hit time out exception.

Now I would to increase a timeout value for a specific transaction which is execute by `Spring framework transactionTemplate`, the code is something as follow:

```
transactionTemplate.execute( new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult( ) {

                        @Override
                        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(
                                TransactionStatus status) {
                            try {
                                // do something here that is no integration 
                                //to database
                            } catch ( BaseException e ) {
                                logger.error(
                                        "hit error ",
                                        e );
                                status.setRollbackOnly( );
                            }
                        }
                    } );
```

I would like to increase this transaction timeout to 300 seconds, because its taking more time to run, sometimes its exceed 120 seconds.

Any way to do on this? Is there any configuration or any method of this `transactionTemplate` to call to increase its timeout period? For example, like `.setTimeOut(300000);`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for   https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/5.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/DefaultTransactionDefinition.html#setTimeout-int-  ?

Comment: I tried `transactionTemplate.setTimeout( 10 );` , it didnt hit timeout after 10 seconds.